# socket io - How does it know if a data changed in DB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, websocket, socket.io

In my Angular5 / NodeJS web app, we have a dashboard that needs real-time data.

If there is any data change in the DB, we want it to be reflected in the front end immediately. Currently, we are reloading the data at regular intervals (say 30 seconds).

Can socket.io help to achieve this?

Not sure, how does it know if there are any data changes in the DB?

Answer (score 2):

You can use SSE (Server Sent Events) a feature in HTML5.

Server-Sent Events (SSE) is a standard describing how servers can initiate data transmission towards clients once an initial client connection has been established. They are commonly used to send message updates or continuous data streams to a browser client and designed to enhance native, cross-browser streaming through a JavaScript API called EventSource, through which a client requests a particular URL in order to receive an event stream.

[Here is simple example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp)

As the SSE are unidirectional it will save efforts and enhance performance, as you just want to send db updates to frontend i.e. single direction only.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: But for his situation SSE might serve him well , there is no harm in trying other ways rather than sticking to one solution.

Comment: Thanks would check